Checking PC compatibility with Windows 10
I have a PC with Windows 7 and wished to upgrade it to Windows 10, but want to check first whether it is compatible with Windows 10 (hardware and installed apps). How do I do this?
Apparently there used to be a downloadable "Get Windows 10" application that did the check, but it appears to be no longer available.
I can run "Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser" in Task Scheduler, and it completes after a while, but then no message is displayed.
Thanks.

As long as you meet or exceed the hardware requirements here, you'll be fine.


While those specifications cover the bare minimum, they won't give you a reasonably well working system. Realistically you need at least 2 CPU cores, 4 GB RAM (and more is really recommended) and 50 GB of diskspace (just for the OS, not counting any additional applications) or you will probably already run out of disk-space on the next WindowsUpdate.

OP wasn't asking that, they were just asking for compatibility. I do agree; it'd run like a pig, but I've answered the question.
